# Formatting Serilog logs

Tags: c#, .net, logging, .net-core, serilog

How do I remove unnecessary information in Serilog logs? The docs seem to have nothing about this.

[image: I want to remove the red part]

I want to remove the red part in the image above

This is my config in appsettings.json

```
  "Serilog": {
"Using": [ "Serilog.Settings.Configuration" ],
"Filter": [
  {
    "Name": "ByIncludingOnly",
    "Args": {
      "expression": "@Level in ['Debug']"
    }
  }
],
"MinimumLevel": {
  "Default": "Debug",
  "Override": {
    "System": "Debug",
    "Microsoft": "Debug"
  }
},
"WriteTo": [
  {
    "Name": "Seq",
    "Args": {
      "serverUrl": "http://localhost:5341/",
      "compact": true
    }
  },
  {
    "Name": "Console"
  },
  {
    "Name": "File",
    "Args": {
      "path": "D:\\dev.SmartCity.Peafowls.Logs\\PeafowlsLog_.txt",
      "rollingInterval": "Day",
      "rollOnFileSizeLimit": true,
      "fileSizeLimitBytes": 4194304
    }
  }
] }
```

Comment: https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-console check the "outputTemplate"

Comment: @TheTanic the output template edits the message, but still the part in the red is shown, regardless..

Comment: Then maybe show your configuration. Otherwise it will be hard to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not completly clear what you want. I can only assume, that you want to display only the Log-Message to the console.

To achieve that, you can add the following outputTemplate to your block:

```
{
    "Name": "Console",
    "Args": {
      "outputTemplate":  "{Message}{NewLine}"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @TheTanic, but this only changes the message(the green part), but the red part of the log is still present. I want to remove that.
https://prnt.sc/25u2tfr

Comment: I cant reprocude your issues at all. Are you sure, that you dont have another logging? Like: Console.WriteLine()?

Comment: In addition, you maybe initialized the console sink twice. One through the configuration and one through code

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that i had this line in the startup class when initializing the logger. `.WriteTo.Providers(providers)`
This is my configuration now:

```
   private void ConfigureLogging(ServiceProvider services, LoggerProviderCollection providers)
    {
        var configuration = services.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();

        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
            .Destructure.ByTransforming<ExpandoObject>(e => new Dictionary<string, object>(e))
            .Enrich.WithProperty("Source", "Peafowls")
             #if DEBUG || STAGE
            .Enrich.WithProperty("Environment", _env)
             #endif
            .CreateLogger();
    }
```